# Requesting a JSON using Request module (encoding issue) - Node.js

Tags: json, node.js

Im trying to request a Json file from a server different from mine but i cant set the right encoding. 
I tried using HTTP module and failed.
Now im trying to do this using the 'Request' module.
The response i get is encoded to i dont know what. maybe utf 16 and is not readable at all.
Note: The json has some Hebrew chars in it.
I added the following to try and fix it but also failed:

```
 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

My code:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var url = 'http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json?v=1';
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.send("Red color");
});
// get Alerts from web-service
app.get('/getAlerts', function(req,res){


request({
    url: url,
    json: true,
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(response.headers) // Print the json response

      res.set({
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }).send(body);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Do you need the bodyparser module?

Answer (score 0):

That API returns a JSON response encoded in `UTF-16-LE`, so you'll have to tell `request` to use that encoding instead.

However, since you're trying to query Pikud Haoref's alerts API, check out `pikud-haoref-api` on npm to do the heavy lifting for you:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pikud-haoref-api